# How to use a CTypedPtrArray

Tags: c++, templates, mfc, structure, typedef

I am newbie at C++. I have created the following structure and typedefs for them in a header:

**Structures.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <afxtempl.h>


struct CITIES
{
    int nId;
    int nUpdateCounter;
    CString strCityName;
    CString strCityRegion;
};
struct PERSONS
{
    int nId;
    int nUpdateCounter;
    CString strFirstName;
    CString strMiddleName;
    CString strLastName;
    CString strUCN;
    int nCityId;
    CString strAddress;
};
struct PHONE_NUMBERS
{
    int nId;
    int nUpdateCounter;
    int nPersonId;
    int nPhoneTypeId;
    CString strPhone;
};
struct PHONE_TYPES
{
    int nId;
    int nUpdateCounter;
    CString strPhoneType;
};

typedef CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, CITIES> CCitiesDataArray;
typedef CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, PERSONS> CPersonsDataArray;
typedef CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, PHONE_NUMBERS> CPhoneNumbersDataArray;
typedef CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, PHONE_TYPES> CPhoneTypesDataArray;
```

So how can I add an city from the source.cpp where I have included Structures.h?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have with your attempts? Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? And you have read [the `CTypedPtrArray` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbk3yw6.aspx)?

Comment: If you are new to C++, why are you using MFC?

Why not use standard C++ types and containers instead? Is MFC offering you something here that the standard language does not provide? std::vector<Cities> mycities; and mycities.push_back(City());

Comment: Is something wrong the the [go-to MFS containers example from MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw2702d6(v=vs.60).aspx) ?

Comment: *"Newbie at C++"* plus *"MFC"* is a sure recipe for disaster. You'll have to learn C, the Windows API, then C++ to even stand a chance to proficiently use MFC.

Comment: what you have there in code are types, but as I understand your question it is about certain instances of those types. It is quite unclear what is the problem. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Even Microsoft doesn't use MFC containers in this day and age, at least from what I have been told.  MFC came along at a time where there were no standard containers, so MFC sort of made sense.  But now, MFC containers are superseded by the standard containers.

Answer (score 2):

`CTypedPtrArray` can only store *pointers* to objects. You are trying to store objects.

You probably don't need `CTypedPtrArray` but `CArray`.

```
  typedef CArray<CITIES, CITIES> CCitiesDataArray;

  ...
  CCitiesDataArray foo;    
  CITIES city = {1, 2, "SomeName", "SomeRegion"};
  foo.Add(city);
  ...
```

But you should probably better use STL containers such as `std::vector` instead of the old MFC containers which are old fashioned and not portable.

Comment: Because it is a course work task in the university. So I really need to use MFC containers and one of the requirements is to write a typedefs for each structure and the use it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a pointer to class/structure name, example:

```
typedef CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, CITIES*> CCitiesDataArray;

void test()
{
    CCitiesDataArray data;
    data.Add(new CITIES{ 100,200,_T("city1"),_T("region1") });

    //or 
    CITIES *ptr = new CITIES;
    ptr->nId = 102;
    ptr->nUpdateCounter = 202;
    ptr->strCityName = _T("city2");
    ptr->strCityRegion = _T("region2");
    data.Add(ptr);

    //do something...

    //cleanup:
    while(data.GetCount())
    {
        delete data.GetAt(0);
        data.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```